# Доказательства — сведения о фактах?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Какой-то умник, не иначе как корифей, если не всех, то множества наук, дал такое определение доказательствам. Прошу дать развернутый комментарий.

Comment: Это сайт по русскому языку.

Comment: Полагаю, что сведения о фактах, это полученная из каких либо источников информация, о том, под каким дубом эти самые факты зарыты.И эти факты должны обладать как минимум относимостью к доказываемому. Сведения о том, что Маша ела кашу, обладают доказательственными свойствами в очень ограниченном диапозоне. Думаю, существительное "сведения", в приведенном определении - мусорное слово. Грамотная формулировка должна быть что нибудь вроде: "Доказательства - факты имеющие непосредственное отношение к предмету доказывания и полученные..." Но, хотелось бы услышать (посмотреть) мнения профессионалов.

Comment: Доказательства  -  фактические данные (сведения о фактах), полученные в предусмотренном законом порядке, которые имеют значения для рассмотрения дела. (Из словаря). Здесь нет "мусырных"  слов.  Такая формулировка абсолютно корректна.

Comment: "Это сайт по русскому языку. – Серж" Вот именно о языке, я и веду речь. Если бы заключения лингвистических экспертиз имели весомое, а лучше решающее юр. значение, та-же коррупция уменьшилась бы на порядок.

Answer (score 1):

С точки зрения **грамматики** предложение составлено верно.

С точки зрения **смысла** оно имеет **частный характер**, что видно из толкового словаря.

**ДОКАЗАТЕЛЬСТВО**, -а; ср. 1. Неопровержимый довод или **факт**, подтверждающий истинность чего-л.

**СВЕДЕНИЕ**,  2. только мн.: сведения,  Познания в какой-л. области.

**ФАКТ**, [от лат. factum - сделанное] 1. Истинное событие, действительное происшествие или реальное явление.

Получается, что доказательство – это (в частном случае) факт, а доказательства (мн. число) – это сведения о таких  фактах.

А вообще говоря, это философская тема, здесь же мы можем дать комментарий только на тему лексики и грамматики.

Comment: Ну да - ну да, доказательство - это факт. а доказательства - это сведения?

Comment: А как вам такой вариант: Х сказал, а У принял ксведению?

Comment: Мне вообще-то никак,  это же не вопрос по русскому языку. Лично мне философия не очень нравится, там можно доказать всё что угодно, так зачем тратить на это время.

Comment: Т.е. я излагаю факты, а никак не сведения о фактах, и аппонент принимает их к сведению. Остаюсь при своем мнении: сведения, в приведенном определении - мусорное слово. Хотелось бы узнать обоснованное подтверждение.

Comment: Arina - Нет, это не философия, это именно язык.

Comment: По конституции, у нас есть государственный язык - Русский. И..., обратите внимание, ни в одной из отраслей права эта норма не раскрывается. Не задумывались почему?

Comment: Язык - это не только искусство, это еще и оружие. Потому то, он не только великий, но еще и могучий.

Comment: @МаксимМародерин, можете обратиться на Грамоту.ру, Грамму.ру и в Институт русского языка. Вам подвердят, что здесь нет "мусырных" слов.